# Getting Unsupported function Truncate error for writer:close()

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

```
RA = pd.read_excel(file_path, header=0, sheet_name="Data")
pivot_df = pd.DataFrame(RA)
#Inserting Pivot
pivot = pivot_df[filter2].pivot_table(index=['a','b', 'c'], values=['Total1','Total2'], aggfunc='sum', margins=True, margins_name='Total')

#copy & pasting pivot to Summary sheet
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay')
pivot.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Summary', index=True)

writer.close()
writer.handles = None
```

At writer.close() i am getting error of **UnsupportedOperation: truncate**. On one system it is working fine but not on another one. I have no idea how to resolve this. Any suggestion please?

Comment: Check out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72409625/unsupportedoperation-truncate and see if it helps at all.

Comment: which version of pandas are you on? and what os thi sis working and on what it's not?

Comment: @eshirvana I have updated python version to the latest on both systems. Same with the packages too "openpyxl". Both has windows OS. Still it is not working. Does the code has any problem?

Comment: @JonSG Thanks for the correction. I checked the post you shared. It is not helpful.

Comment: but what version pf pandas are you on? what `print(pd.__version__)`  returns?

Comment: @eshirvana  2.1.4

Answer (score 0):

well put it here as it won't fit it in the comment , how about using context manager :

```
RA = pd.read_excel(file_path, header=0, sheet_name="Data")
pivot_df = pd.DataFrame(RA)
#Inserting Pivot
pivot = pivot_df[filter2].pivot_table(index=['a','b', 'c'], values=['Total1','Total2'], aggfunc='sum', margins=True, margins_name='Total')

#copy & pasting pivot to Summary sheet
with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
    pivot.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Summary', index=True)
```

Comment: Still getting the same error on

with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:

UnsupportedOperation: truncate

Comment: @AkshayKumar then it might be the openpyxl version